# Using res.send() for sending the response in nodeJs

Tags: node.js

I'm a beginner in nodeJs, I have created node server and write simple program, Sending the response I am using "response.end('some text')" working fine, but instead of using 'end' if I am trying to send response using 'send', then its throwing error "response.send is not a function."

Comment: Have a look at SO's help to understand how to ask. For example a question without code can hardly be answered.

Comment: Post some code so that it can be debugged.

Comment: Following is my code :

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   
   //response.end('Hello World\n');
   response.send('Hello Node\n');
}).listen(8081);

Answer (score 4):

You have probably created an HTTP server based on the [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) module.

`response`, which is a [`http.ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) instance, does not have a `.send` method. It does, as you found out, have a [`.end`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback) method, though.

My guess is that you have seen some [Express](http://expressjs.com/) code. Express is a framework to build HTTP servers, and it provides additional functionality on top of the regular `http` module.

One of those additional functions is a [`.send`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send) method for HTTP response instances:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = app.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('hello world!');
});
```

Comment: Can't we send without using express? Pls tell.

Comment: @Rohit. use `http` to create a server and `response.write()/response.end()` to send back a response.

Comment: I have been trying the same for long. Nothing is being shown using AngularJS.

Comment: @Rohit. if you have a specific question, you can ask it on this site.

Comment: Asked, Please help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011625/output-is-not-being-shown-using-angularjs-when-data-is-retrieved-from-nodejs