# Output is not being shown using AngularJS when data is retrieved from NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Here is my back end code using NodeJS, by which I am trying to send JSON data. -

```
con.query(sql, function(err, result, fields){
    if(err) throw err;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var Dict = {"records":result};
    res.end(JSON.stringify(Dict));
  });
```

Here is my front end code using AngularJS, by which I am trying to show JSON data on the browser-

```
<body> 
      <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <p ng-model="rows">
            {{ rows }}
            </p>
      </div>
 <script>
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$http){
    $http.get("http://localhost:1208").then(function(response){
    $scope.rows = response.data.records;
    });
 });
 </script>
</body>
```

But when I run this Angularjs file code on the browser, it shows nothing. Can anyone help me to fix this problem? I wanna show my JSON data on the browser.

Comment: have you tried consoling the response in the front end and checking ?

Comment: Replace `<p ng-model="rows">
            {{ rows }}
            </p>` by `<pre>{{rows|json}}</pre>` for easier debug.

Answer (score 0):

is not an input element and it does not have **`ng-model`** tag,

remove and change it as,

```
 <p>
   {{ rows }}
 </p>
```

Comment: Thanks but problem still persists.

Comment: console.log( response.data.records);

Comment: what is the output when you do that

Comment: Sorry, I am beginner. How can I do that? Consoling angular data?

Comment: $http.get("http://localhost:1208").then(function(response){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.records));
    });

Comment: what is the output when you do the above

Comment: THanks it is showing : {{rows|json}} as I have updated according to above's comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157789/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-rohit).

Comment: sorry didn't work. I will try some other day. giving up for now. -_-